# VBNET: Parent Control > Child Control

Tags: nested

SUMMARY
One main form which contains a usercontrol(Child), which in turn contains another user control(Child_1) like so: MAIN(FORM) -> Child(USERCONTROL) -> Child_1(USERCONTROL).
On Child there is a DGV control with some rows. Also there are two public readonly properties (IdBase and IdUser) who get their data from Child -> DGV.CurrentRow.
What i need: On Child_1 to be able to access the two properties on Child (IdBase and IdUser).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i've solved this but i don't know how to delete it, since it doesn't have one answer. I just didn't know enough :)

Answer (score 0):

What i have working but i'm not sure if it's correct:

1. On each Usercontrol (Child and Child_1):

- i have set a variable as fMain
- i have a public property SetParent() which sets the Variable fMain as Main which i call when MAIN loads Child;

2. On usercontrol Child_1

- i have set a variable as fChild
- i have a public property SetChild() which sets the Variable fChild as Child when Child loads Child_1.
  This way i can access both MAIN's and Child's properties and controls